# New review system reduces our ability to help out new users?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, post-review

So, apparently anonymous edits need to be approved by two people in order to be approved. I approve a lot of edits from new users who are trying to help the site. They're usually both good and uncontroversial.

Just now, a new user made a post and then accidentally (but obviously) edited it as anonymous. I tried to approve that edit to help her out, but instead it's just sitting there in the queue.

How does this help welcome new users into our community? How does it take load off of moderators?

Comment: For anyone wondering why this changed, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151536) Meta.SO question explains that it is intended to reduce the number of bad edits being approved